# I'm looking for any/all mirror image prime numbers, which multiplied together equal the Triangular Value of either one of the primes.

Tags: complex-analysis

Not sure how to ask this question.
I would like to know of any/all prime numbers, which are mirror images of each other, which when multiplied together give the same value as the Triangular Value of either one of the primes.
I give the following example: Prime1 = 37 and Prime2 = 73 (mirror images of each other)
When multiplied together (37x73) = 2701 which happens to be the 73rd Triangular Value, i.e. T73 also equals 2701.